# What (if anything) is the connection between the Feit-Higman Theorem and the regular plane tilings?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, tiling, finite-geometry, incidence-geometry

Here are two facts that are superficially similar.

> **Tiling Theorem:** The only [regular tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons) of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are achieved by triangles, squares, and hexagons.
>
> **Feit-Higman Theorem:** The only finite balanced (same number of points and lines) nontrivial [generalized polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygon) are generalized triangles, squares, and hexagons.

In particular, there is some intuitive sense in which a generalized polygon can be seen as a "tiling" of a partial linear space by triangles/squares/hexagons, although I am not sure how exactly to formalize this.  So, my question is: is there a unified reason or principle, or perhaps a theorem that generalizes both of the above, which explains why triangles, squares, and hexagons emerge as the special "tilable shapes" in both of these settings?  Or is this just a mathematical coincidence?

Comment: $\phi(n)=2$ if and only if $n=3,4,6$. Only the 3rd, 4th, and 6th roots of unity generate extensions of degree 2.

Comment: The $C(p)-T(q)$-small cancelation condition defines groups of non-positive curvature if and only if $\frac 1p+\frac 1q=\frac 12$ which happens only when $p=3, 4$ or $6$ (and $q=6, 4$ or $3$).